# How can I extract multiple .gz log files in command line

Tags: command-line, compression

I have a years worth of log files that are all in .gz files. Is there a command I can use to extract these all at once into their current directory? I tried unzip *.gz but doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: please edit your question to include exact error messages or other exact evidence of "but doesn't work". On many/most Linux, you need to use `gunzip`, not `unzip`. `gunzip *.gz` should work. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

For googles sake, since it took me here, it's as simple as this:

```
gzip -dc access.log.*.gz > access.log
```

Comment: That puts the output all into one file. It looks like the OP wants them all decompressed to their own individual files.

Answer (score 0):

shell sciprt?

```
#!/bin/ksh

TEMPFILE=tempksh_$$.tmp                                          #create a file name
> $TEMPFILE                                                      #create a file w/ name

ls -l | grep '.*\.gz$' \                                         #make dynamic shell script
      | awk '{printf "unzip %s;\n", $9;}' \                      #with unzip cmd for each item
      >>  $TEMPFILE                                              #and write to TEMPFILE


chmod 755 $TEMPFILE                                              #give run permissions
./$TEMPFILE                                                      #and run it
rm -f $TEMPFILE                                                  #clean up
```

Untested but i think you get the idea....

Actually a little fiddling and gets far simpler...

```
 set -A ARR *.gz;
 for i in ${characters[@]}; do `unzip $i`; done;
 unset ARR;
```

Comment: Thanks gb but that's way over my head, I actually found another way to do it. There is a gunzip command and that seems to have worked. I just did: gunzip *\.gz

Comment: Cool well whatever works. But dont let scripting scare you... if you going to be doing a lot of cli work, learning it will make your expience far better.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a comment, you want to use `gunzip`, not `gzip`. `unzip` is for `.zip` files. `gzip` is for `.gz` files. Two completely different formats.

```
gunzip *.gz
```

or:

```
gzip -d *.gz
```

That will delete the `.gz` files after successfully decompressing them. If you'd like to keep all of the original `.gz` files, then:

```
gzip -dk *.gz
```